# Why is Excel adding quotation marks?

Tags: excel, vba

My application writes data into a column of a worksheet

```
Dim dest As Range
Set dest = Range("A1:A1")

dest.Cells(1) = "NUMBER_OF_FIELDS"
dest.Cells(2) = "BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT"
dest.Cells(3) = "SAMPLE_ID"
dest.Cells(4) = "END_DATA_FORMAT"
dest.Cells(5) = ""
dest.Cells(6) = "NUMBER_OF_SETS" & vbTab & numRows
dest.Cells(7) = "BEGIN_DATA" & vbTab & "LAB_L" & vbTab & "LAB_A" & vbTab & "LAB_B"
```

When I copy the worksheet column and paste it into a blank text document (Windows Notepad), lines six and seven are surrounded by quotation marks, e.g.,

```
"NUMBER_OF_SETS 52"
"BEGIN_DATA    LAB_L   LAB_A    LAB_B"
```

If I replace the vbTab character by a space, lines six and seven are no longer quoted. This is not a solution, because tabs are required. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can't use tabs to get what you want. Excel is trying to protect you for when you copy the data back in to a spreadsheet by preventing the lines with tabs from spilling out into multiple columns - that's what the quotes are doing. It's like when saving a CSV file when a field has a `,` in it, then the CSV has that field surrounded by double-quotes to protect the comma.

Comment: This code is from an application which must run on both Windows and MacOS. I'm developing on Windows, where I use the file system object for writing to a file specified by the user. Since FSO is only for Excel on Windows, my MacOS code writes to a worksheet (as shown above) and requires the user to copy and paste from the worksheet into a file. I'm sure there's a better solution.

Comment: You can use the [open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) statement to write files with a basic vba language feature, so that should also work on MacOS.

Comment: I just tried that (I wasn't familiar with the feature) but I vba still adds quotation marks. I'm going to make a new post to stackoverflow.

Comment: @jisner - VBA isn't adding quotation-marks. Excel is when you copy from the cells.